# Local variable with multiple value list

Tags: sql, sql-server, local-variables

I use Excel connection to connect to SQL Server to query data from SQL server to Excel.

I have below WHERE clause in the Excel connection couple times.  I need to replace the WHERE multiple value list from time to time. To simply the replacement, I want to use a local parameter, @Trans.  With the local parameter, I can change it only and all SQL will use it to query.

```
WHERE Type in ('R','D','C')
```

If it is single option, below code works.

```
DECLARE @TRans CHAR(200)= 'R';
SELECT .....
WHERE Type in (@Trans)
```

If it is multiple options, the below code does not works

```
DECLARE @TRans CHAR(200)= 'R,D,C';
SELECT .....
WHERE Type in (@Trans)

DECLARE @TRans CHAR(200)= '''R'''+','+'''D'''+','+'''C''';
SELECT .....
WHERE Type in (@Trans)
```

How to declare @Trans for multiple value list, for example ('R','D','C')?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @TRans VARCHAR(200)= '''R'',''D'',''C''';
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE Type in (' + @Trans + ');'

EXEC @sql
```

Take note of the quotes for the values in @TRans since these character values.

If you want to check the value of @sql which you will see the constructed sql statement, replace EXEC @sql with PRINT @sql.

Result of @sql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Type in ('R','D','C');
```

Comment: I cannot use EXEC.  My sql is Excel data link connection.

Comment: you may check this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3436/passing-dynamic-query-values-from-excel-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by now, SQL Server does NOT support macro substition.  This leaves a couple of options.  One is to split the string.

If not 2016, here is a quick in-line approach which does not require a Table-Valued Function

**Example**

```
Declare @Trans varchar(max)='R,D,C'  -- Notice no single quotes

Select ...
 Where Type in (
                Select RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Trans,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table named `LocalParameter` and keep local variables there. You can only get datas by updating `LocalParameter` table without changing the `queries`.

```
CREATE TABLE LocalParameter (Trans VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO LocalParameter
VALUES
(
    ',R,'
)
```

With `LIKE` you can use it like this:

```
SELECT .....
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 A.Trans FROM LocalParameter A) LIKE ',' + Type + ','
```

To change `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE LocalParameter
SET Trans = ',R,D,C,'
```

Queries:

```
SELECT .....
WHERE (SELECT TOP 1 A.Trans FROM LocalParameter A) LIKE ',' + Type + ','
```

Local variables are added to the beginning and end of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split method to split csv values as shown below

```
DECLARE @delimiter      VARCHAR(10)=','
DECLARE @input_string   VARCHAR(200)='R,D,C'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(@input_string,0,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string)) AS ExtractedString, 
        SUBSTRING(@input_string,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string) + 1,LEN(@input_string)) AS PartString
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(PartString,0,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,PartString)) AS ExtractedString, 
        SUBSTRING(PartString,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,PartString)+1,LEN(PartString)) AS PartString 
    FROM CTE WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter,PartString)>0
)
SELECT ExtractedString FROM CTE 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@delimiter,REVERSE(@input_string))>0 
        THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@input_string),0,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,REVERSE(@input_string)))) 
        ELSE @input_string END
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This split method doesnt have any loops so it will be fast. then you integrate this with your query as below mentioned

```
DECLARE @delimiter      VARCHAR(10)=','
DECLARE @input_string   VARCHAR(200)='R,D,C'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(@input_string,0,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string)) AS ExtractedString, 
        SUBSTRING(@input_string,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string) + 1,LEN(@input_string)) AS PartString
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input_string)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(PartString,0,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,PartString)) AS ExtractedString, 
        SUBSTRING(PartString,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,PartString)+1,LEN(PartString)) AS PartString 
    FROM CTE WHERE CHARINDEX(@delimiter,PartString)>0
)
SELECT * FROM [YourTableName] WHERE Type IN
(SELECT ExtractedString FROM CTE 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@delimiter,REVERSE(@input_string))>0 
        THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@input_string),0,CHARINDEX(@delimiter,REVERSE(@input_string)))) 
        ELSE @input_string END
)OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible add a new table and then join to it in all your queries:

```
CREATE TABLE SelectedType
(
   [Type] CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO SelectedType
VALUES ('R','D','C')
```

Then your queries become:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable MT
INNER JOIN SelectedType [ST]
   ON ST.[Type] = MT.[Type]
```

If you need to add, update or delete types then update the rows in SelectedType table.

This has the benefit of using SET BASED queries, is easy to understand and easy to add, update or delete required types.